# Estimate Sobolev function by its derivative on a ball

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

If $f$ is a smooth function and $f(0)=0$, it is clear that $\|f\|_{L^\infty(B)}$ can be estimated (for any Ball $B$) if $\|\nabla f\|_\infty$ is known.

My question is whether something similar can be done for Sobolev function and the $L^2$-norm. More precisely: Suppose $f\in H^1_0(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_\epsilon)$ for a ball $B_\epsilon$ of small radius. Is it possible to get an estimate like
$$\|f\|_{L^2(B_r)} \leq C(r-\epsilon)\|\nabla f\|_{L^2(B_r)} $$ ?

The reason I'm asking is that the naive approach to this fails:

$\int_{B_r} |f(x)|^2 dx = \int_{B_r}\big|\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt}f(tx)dt\,\big|^2dx$

$\leq r^2\int_{B_r}\int_0^1|\nabla f(tx)|^2dt\,dx$

Now, if one exchanges the integrals and changes the variable to $tx=y$, it fails to be integrable in $t$:

$"=" r^2\int_0^1\int_{B_r}\frac 1 t |\nabla f(y)|^2dy\,dt$

Comment: This looks like a form of the [Poincaré inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality). Or is the issue to get the vanishing coefficient as $r\to \epsilon$? (I don't think $(r-\epsilon)$ is the right asymptotic for that.)

Comment: Yes, the issue is to get the vanishing coefficient as $r\to\epsilon$. The constant $C$ shouldn't depend on $r$.

Also, it's not exactly a Poincaré inequality since $f$ is not zero on $\partial B_r$.

You're probably right that $(r-\epsilon) $ is not the right asymptotics, but anything that goes to zero would be OK as a start.